# Tag Control Information Byte Order

Tags: vlan

I need to extract the 12-bit VLAN ID from the 16-bit TCI section of the 802.1Q tag in an Ethernet frame.

I already have the TCI extracted and stored as a `uint16_t`.
I know that bytes arrive in Big Endian format as below, and that if the packets were one 16-bit value they would need to be reordered from 0x0123 -> 0x2301.
[image: TIC Byte Diagram]

However, the four non-VLAN ID bits can be ignored as they're not part of the 12-bit value.

**My question is: is the nibble with value 0x1 the most or least significant nibble of the VLAN ID, ie. is the value 0x123 or 0x231?**

To me it seems to make sense that the value would be 0x123. If the bytes were reordered the overall value would be 0x2301, and another field would separate sections of the VLAN ID value.

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate question. I haven't been able find an answer or similar question.

Comment: This is a programming question. To work with the number(s), they need to be in *host byte order*.  (see also: `ntohl` and `ntohs`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IEEE 802 networks don't transfer nibbles. There's a defined bit order (which you can ignore on the MAC level) and a defined byte order.

The part that you've marked *IGNORED* contains the PCP and DEI bits. They are the four most significant bits in the first byte.

See IEEE 802.1Q clause 9.6 and Annex G for more details (available from http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68 for free after registration).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my situation the the PCP and DEI bits must be zeroed out leaving just the VLAN ID value.
If I've understood your answer correctly I can just zero out the four MSBs, for example `var = var & 0x0FFF`
So, in relation to the original question, the VLAN ID would be 0x123?
To be clear, the `uint16_t` storing the TCI will be in network byte order. The host is little-endian.

Hopefully what I'm asking is clear. Apologies if not.
I'm also currently reading to section you mentioned to see if it makes things clearer to me.

Comment: Without the exact bit order your diagram is ambiguous - if we assume the usual 7...0 order then that is correct. The network byte order is big endian though. If you access the word on a little-endian system the byte order is reversed.